# Excel - Restrict the value of a cell

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

I have two sheets set up in excel...on of the sheets is a list of contacts and the other sheets is a list of food items.

On the food item sheet a user can pull down a list of contacts to associate it with that food item.

This is all working fine, but the problem is, the user can put in a value that is not on that list by typing.

Is there a way to only allow values in the drop down list?

Comment: yes it is. see [**this link**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-or-delete-a-drop-down-list-HP010072599.aspx) for details

Comment: Didn't know anything about the Super User Forum... yes it probably is better for that site @pnuts....

Comment: @simoco that link shows you how to create the drop down box but not how to limit the values entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a drop-down list from a range of cells, use the Validation command under the Data menu.

**1.** To create a list of valid entries for the drop-down list, type the entries in a single column or row without blank cells. For example:

[image]

**2.** NOTE   You may want to sort the data in the order that you want it to appear in the drop-down list.

**3.** If you want to use another worksheet or another workbook, do one of the following:
Use a different worksheet in the same workbook     Type the list on that worksheet, and then define a name for the list.

Use a different worksheet in a different workbook    Type the list on that worksheet, and then define a name with an external reference to the list.

**1.** Select the cell where you want the drop-down list.

**2.** On the Data menu, click Validation, and then click the Settings tab.
In the Allow box, click List.

**3.** To specify the location of the list of valid entries, do one of the following:

**4.** If the list is in the current worksheet, enter a reference to your list in the Source box.

**5.** If the list is on a different worksheet in the same workbook or a different workbook, enter the name that you defined for your list in the Source box.

**6.** In both cases, make sure that the reference or name is preceded with an equal sign (=). For            example, enter =ValidDepts.

Make sure that the In-cell drop-down check box is selected.

**7.** To specify whether the cell can be left blank, select or clear the Ignore blank check box.

Optionally, display an input message when the cell is clicked.

***And then you will get something like::***

[image]

***and if you try to add some other value then the list ,you will get a message like this::***

[image]

Comment: This is SHOULD be the answer... and it works.. how you said.. apart from the last bit.. I can still enter what I want.. even though I can see the list

Comment: @user2537315  when you click the validation in data menu ,a small window will pop up ,click Error Alert ,select style to stop and you can write the error message whatever you want to show whenever a wrong data is entered.

Comment: Its working now... the KEY IS... in the Data validation > Settings window you have to UN-CHECK the Ignore blank.. box.. now it works.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data validation button and then there is an option under settings you can select the list option from the allow box and then select your source information (from a list you have placed in some cells elsewhere in the workbook). Then it will give an error if a value is typed that is not in the list.

Under the error alert tab you can even put a custom message that shows up for an invalid value.

Comment: That's would I would think.. but it is allowing me to put in anything.. I defined an error message, thinking that may be the reason it allows me to type in anything, but its still not working...

Comment: @user2537315 That is strange, I have a few spread sheets with this type of validation and it always throws up an error message if you type anything that isn't valid, however the error only comes up after you try and change to a new cell, not during input.